# Outlook Javascript Add-Ins for Folders

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I want to build an Office JS Add-In for Outlook which interacts with a folder, so that users can apply external properties to that folder.  However, it seems that the only interfaces are with messages and appointments.  Is there any way to accomplish what I would like to (i.e. utilize the API to take in and show data stored externally about a folder)?

Answer (score 0):

You can make EWS calls from Outlook web add-ins, see [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) for more information. It seems you are interested in the [UpdateFolder operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/updatefolder-operation).

Comment: I will look further into this.  My concern is more to the point that the Extension Points for the Add-Ins all seem to be focused around Messages and Appointments, whereas I am looking for a way for the add-in to deal specifically with a selected folder. Am I making sense?

Comment: Yes, but that is the current design of Outlook Web Add-ins.  Are you targeting Outlook Desktop?  Your add-in would be more visible there because you can put it on the ribbon.  Your add-in may show most of the time but not all the time, it depends on whether there is a message is being read (usually there is), or if you are on another view.  There are, of course, other more unique scenarios where your add-in may not appear, but it is by design.